# av_read_frame of ffmpeg in windows always returning packet.stream_index as 0

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to demuxer, for some video like the windows's sample  Wildlife.wmv, the av_read_frame is always returning packet.stream_index=0. This leads the video queue very big and memory overflow. I get 15 frames of video, but only 1 frame of audio. Is there some options to control the av_read_frame, so I can read frames like: video-audio-video-audio, in this way it's easy to sync AV and keep queue balance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**av_read_frame** just returns whatever is stored in the file in the order it finds it without any validation.

So the answeris no, there is no FFmpeg option for this, but you can try to control this yourself after getting each packet.

[av_read_frame specification](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.9/group__lavf__decoding.html#g4fdb3084415a82e3810de6ee60e46a61)

In the past we developed a media player and for problems like this we read audio & video in different threads and then synched presentation ourselves.

Comment: Hi Maxito, thank your answer. I have thought about create more thread to process different stream, but maybe the reading IO performance will be affect? And I found after the 'avformat_open_input', the 'avformat_find_stream_info' will cached some packets, in my media file, after avformat_find_stream_info, the AVStream::codec_info_nb_frames of video is 109 frames, but audio's is 1. This is the reason why after playing I got 109 video frames immediately? I have tried using 'avcodec_flush_buffers' to flush them or using av_seek_file to clear it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If threads are used correctly it shouldn't affect performance, but it all depends on what you are actually trying to achieve with your program and what you will do with the data. I am not sure if that information has anything to do with the order _av_read_frame_  gives you audio or video since I don't know how does _avformat_find_stream_info_ works internally.